# Are there any large satellite hardware suppliers for components or buses? (For CubeSats, SmallSats, Rovers, etc...)

Tags: spacecraft, cots

I am looking for online catalogs of hardware either semi-COTS or full COTS (radios, antennas, thrusters, command and data handing boards, batteries, attitude control, etc...) that can be used in space applications. I found [CubeSatShop.com,](https://www.cubesatshop.com/) however, it only pertains to CubeSats and some SmallSat systems. Is there any other large online catalogs of parts for either/or CubeSats, SmallSats, Rovers, LargeSats, etc...?

Also I've been looking for a large list of spacecraft/rover scientific instruments, however, I have not been able to find such a database. Any recommendations?

Comment: Sadly, most of this stuff is so specialized (and so focused around consultingware) you will rarely if ever find catalogs with prices, or even ones without.

Comment: Not a database, but you might play around with the various companies held by Redwire. They're building up quite a stable of component manufacturers.

Answer (score 2):

The best and most complete spacecraft/satellite parts shop I've ran across is [satcatalog.com](https://satcatalog.com/). Satcatalog appears to have a large selection of COTS and semi-COTS hardware for CubeSats, SmallSats, and even medium/large satellites. Cubesatshop is another decent one, however I've found [satcatalog.com](https://satcatalog.com/) to be far better, since they offer more variety and have better search tools.

TLDR: Largest Spacecraft Shop: [SatCatalog.com](https://satcatalog.com/)

*Largest one that I am aware of*